# Cannot add a reference to PCL from C++/Cli project

Tags: c++-cli, portable-class-library

I have a Portable Class Library project, Net 4.5 platform activated. I can use it in other C# projects without problems.
Now, I have a C++/Cli project and I need to use some classes of the above PCL project.
When I add the reference to the PCL project, Visual Studio 2012 gives me an error because of different target platforms.

Is there a problem to add references to PCL projects from C++/Cli projects?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This questionas was replied but for some unknown reason, the response has been deleted:

The solution is to edit the vcxproj file and change

```
 <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to

```
 <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Comment: put 5 space characters before source code to do it nice to see :) also after 1 day, I think, you can assign your answer as the correct answer