# Including a PCL library DLL in a C++ winrt Project

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, portable-class-library

I created Portable Class Library that I want to use in various WinRT projects. I can use this PCL dll in C# Winrt Apps, VB WinRT Apps, silverlight and Windows Phone. But for some reason, I can't successfully add the library to my C++ project. The error that I get when I try this is:

> Could not add a reference to file 'C:\Users\xyz\pqr.dll' because it is
>   neither a .NET assembly nor a registered ActiveX control.

I saw the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321958/cannot-add-a-reference-to-pcl-from-c-cli-project) on SO earlier and the OP posted a solution that seems to work for him. I tried to find the following line as the original question suggested but I can't find it in the vcxproj file.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Since I can't post a comment on the original question, I figured I should post another question here.

Any Ideas?

**Edit:** 
My project setup looks something like this:

- Lets assume that My PCL library is called A.dll.
- My WinRT component is called B.winmd.
- Now, B.winmd uses A.dll internally and creates a wrapper around it.

Now when I want to create a Store App C in C++, I have to add references to both A.dll and B.winmd in my project C. If I just include B.winmd, I get a runtime exception the first time something from A.dll is used. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A C++ application does not know how to execute managed code.  If you want to create a library using C# and make it available to another runtime environment like C++ or Javascript then you have to create a Windows Runtime Component project.  Its public interface is limited to WinRT compatible types to allow the interop between runtime environments to work.  Lots of other little rules.

The MSDN starter page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx).

Comment: I wonder how many types in PCL are not compatible with WinRT. It would certainly be nice if these converged.

Comment: I agree.  But I think I am using the right subset of PCL because my winmd + dll setup works fine on C# and VB winrt apps but I can't get it to work on c++.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you use PCL.  The C++ code can only use WinRT types, it doesn't know beans about .NET types.  PCL is only interesting if you want your library to be used by managed code on other platforms (phone, xbox, etc).

Comment: Right, but WinRT projects .NET types from a .NET WinRT component to types that work in other languages. If a PCL component could be a WinRT component at the same time - you could use it in all flavors of .NET AND in WinRT.

Comment: hmm...  So is this an artificial restriction imposed by Visual Studio? When I copy the PCL library to the Debug\CppApp\AppX\ folder, the App start working as expected. I just don't know how to package my component so that the DLL reaches the appx folder.

Comment: @Filip - the language project works only one way.  The type system of WinRT is very simple, just COM with metadata annotations that allow a language projection to emulate features that COM doesn't have.  Like implementation inheritance and generics.  That cannot work the other way around, you cannot map a rich type system like .NET to  simple one like WinRT.  Which is why WRC classes must be sealed and cannot use generics and only use types that another runtime environment like C++ or Javascript has access to.  WinRT types.

Comment: OK, so these two can't easily be combined without forsaking some .NET features in a WinRT component, but they could make an even more portable PCL library that would work as a WinRT component if none of the features possible in PCL were exposed through WinRT, for example limiting generics to only be used internally in the library. I'm just a UI developer and I don't know too much about internals of the assemblies and ABIs, but it still sounds like something Microsoft could pull off.

Comment: You can already do all of those things without PCL.  Using generics is fine, as long as you don't make a generic type public and thus expose it to another runtime environment that doesn't know anything about generics.  Like C++ and Javascript.  PCL is a pure .NET platform detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your message should be a good hint there - a PCL library is a .NET library. WinRT projects need WinRT components. You need to create a .NET-based WinRT component that will wrap your PCL library to make it usable in non-.NET languages.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "component that will wrap your PCL library to ...". I do have a Winrt component that uses the PCL library. But If I reference the winmd file without referencing the PCL dll then there are errors that show up.  Do I just need to copy the dll in the same directory as winmd file to make things work?

Comment: If you create a new Windows Store project in VS - one of the templates you will see is "Windows Runtime Component". I think you would need to reference your PCL library in that component and create a proxy type/method/member for each PCL symbol you want exposed to other WinRT languages.

Comment: I don't think I am understanding this properly. Lets assume that My PCL library is called A.dll. My WinRT component is called B.winmd. Now, B.winmd uses A.dll internally and creates a wrapper around it. Now when I want to create a Store App C, I have to add references to both A.dll and B.winmd in my project C. If I just include B.winmd, I get a runtime exception the first time something from A.dll is used. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done that before, so I am not sure. Personally I would simply include source projects for A and B in solution C. If you  want to use the binaries and want A to always be deployed with B - I think NuGet works only in .NET, but perhaps you could write a vsix like in [Tim Heuer's post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx). Otherwise - you might just need to reference both to force them both to be deployed with your app.

Comment: Thanks again for being so patient. After my last post, I manually copied A.dll to the AppX directory of App C and once I do that the app works fine. So I don't think this is an issue about support not being present. I just need to figure out how to package it properly so that both A.dll and B.winmd are deployed together. (A.dll and B.winmd are supposed to be part of an SDK that I am working on and hence including the source in the same solution as C is not a solution for me.) Thanks again for your answers though!